# domain dependence of best constant in inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Take $N \ge 3$ and consider the inequality 
$$ \| \nabla u\|_{L^N} \le C(\Omega) \| \Delta u \|_{L^\frac{N}{2}} $$ for all $ u \in W^{2,\frac{N}{2}}(\Omega) \cap W^{1,N}_0(\Omega)$  where $ \Omega$ is a smooth bounded domain in $ R^N$.   My question is can we show the best constant $ C(\Omega)$ is independent of $ \Omega$.       It does not depend on scaling; but maybe it is still domain dependent?

Note,  if we had restricted the functions to $ W^{2,\frac{N}{2}}_0(\Omega)$ then we could extend by zero outside and maybe relate to inequalities on $ R^N$.
Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: I think something like $u(x)=R-|x|$ on $1\le |x| \le R$ (and make it smooth) will work as a counterexample.

Comment: I am confused... your saying the inequality is false or that it does depend on the domain or ?

Comment: That it depends on $\Omega$.

Comment: what is the domain for your example?  the annulus  $1<|x|<R$  or the ball of radius $R$ and the function on the annulus is $ R-|x|$  (and smooth otherwise) ?